# Blog on a separate server from WooCommerce WITHOUT effecting SEO?

Tags: blog, seo, subdomains

I am wondering if it's possible to put the blog portion of my WordPress site on an entirely separate server, but without effecting SEO.

The obvious and easy choice would of course be a subdomain (i.e. blog.mywebsite.com), but that effectively neuters any SEO benefits of the blog. The entire purpose of my blog is specifically to attract traffic to the rest of the website.

The reason why I would like to do this for the purpose of load balancing. I will get significantly more traffic on my blog than on the actual WooCommerce portion of my website, so I can balance the traffic between the two and also use servers which are more suited to each purpose. Ultimately saving on expenses by using specialized servers.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this is not really WordPress related, but rather server (infrastructure). WP doesn't necessarily care where it runs. To the question: does it really matter? As long as your blog doesn't have dynamic elements, you can put all pages in a full page cache and now the load on the server for delivering the pages is extremely low.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the suggestion, I will absolutely do the full page cache for my blog. I'll close the post.